# How to store multiple checkbox values in reactive form in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am working on angular2 application and getting problem in storing values of multiple check boxes in form field.

Type script

```
form : FormGroup;
cities = ["Mohali", "Chandigarh", "Ludhiana", "Amritsar"];
zip_codes = ["282001", "456123", "123456", "140412"];

constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder)
{
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
       cities   : this.formBuilder.array(["Mohali", "Amritsar"]),
       zip_codes : this.formBuilder.array(["456123"])
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let city of cities">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="cities" value="city">
    <span>{{city}}</span>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let zipCode of zip_codes">
    <inbput type="checkbox" formControlName="zip_codes" value="zipCode">
     <span>{{zipCode}}</span>
</div>
```

I want to store checked cities and zip_codes in form field and when I have default values in form field then the values are in array will be checked automatically.

Comment: Which items should be checked?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One way would be like this:

1) Setup `FormArray` fields with `false` default values

```typescript
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  cities   : this.formBuilder.array(this.cities.map(x => !1)),
  zip_codes : this.formBuilder.array(this.zip_codes.map(x => !1))
});
```

2) The template will look like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let city of cities; let i = index" formArrayName="cities">
  <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
  <span>{{city}}</span>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let zipCode of zip_codes; let i = index" formArrayName="zip_codes">
  <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
  <span>{{zipCode}}</span>
</div>
```

3) Submit form

```typescript
convertToValue(key: string) {
  return this.form.value[key].map((x, i) => x && this[key][i]).filter(x => !!x);
}

onSubmit() {
  const valueToStore = Object.assign({}, this.form.value, {
    cities: this.convertToValue('cities'),
    zip_codes: this.convertToValue('zip_codes')
  });
  console.log(valueToStore);
}
```

4) Default values

```typescript
const defaultCities = ["Mohali", "Amritsar"];
const defaultZipCodes = ["456123"];
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  cities: this.formBuilder.array(this.cities.map(x => defaultCities.indexOf(x) > -1)),
  zip_codes: this.formBuilder.array(this.zip_codes.map(x => defaultZipCodes.indexOf(x) > -1))
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/idbjlCxND5aes2Zx2iFT?p=preview)**

Comment: I don't want this type of output ( "cities": [true,  true,  true, true]), I want ("cities" : ["Mohali", "Amritsar"]).

Comment: @LakhvirSingh Try to submit button

Comment: Thank you its works but you are using variable to store defaultCities and defaultZipCodes but in my situation I don't know  that I will get cities array from api because every array and its html generating based on api response. If I get cities array in api then it will automatically generate  its html and add new control in form.

Comment: @LakhvirSingh I used variables just for example. You can update value after getting from server like this.form.get('cities').patchValue(this.cities.map(x => citiesFromServer.indexOf(x) > -1)); https://plnkr.co/edit/M5mIx5idfUDpRmiaxCPk?p=preview

Comment: How can I get values of form if I use Object.assign() separately on both fields (cities, zip_codes). Because when I am using separately on both fields I will get only one field value at a time, but I want both fields value together but using Object.assign() separately.

Comment: Create example in plunker

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

I liked very much the answer of @yurzui
But had an issue with getting the values back .. So..

My solution - solved it for Angular 5 with Material View
The connection is through the

> formArrayName="notification"
>
> (change)="updateChkbxArray(n.id, $event.checked, 'notification')"

This way it can work for multiple checkboxes arrays in one form.
Just set the name of the controls array to connect each time.

```js
constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private http: Http,
  private codeTableService: CodeTablesService) {

  this.codeTableService.getnotifications().subscribe(response => {
      this.notifications = response;
    })
    ...
}


createForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    notification: this.fb.array([])...
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.createForm();
}

updateChkbxArray(id, isChecked, key) {
  const chkArray = < FormArray > this.form.get(key);
  if (isChecked) {
    chkArray.push(new FormControl(id));
  } else {
    let idx = chkArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == id);
    chkArray.removeAt(idx);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <section class="checkbox-section text-center" *ngIf="notifications  && notifications.length > 0">
    <label class="example-margin">Notifications to send:</label>
    <p *ngFor="let n of notifications; let i = index" formArrayName="notification">
      <mat-checkbox class="checkbox-margin" (change)="updateChkbxArray(n.id, $event.checked, 'notification')" value="n.id">{{n.description}}</mat-checkbox>
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

At the end you are getting to save the form with array of original records id's to save/update.
[image: The UI View]

[image: The relevat part of the json of the form]

> Will be happy to have any remarks for improvement.

Here is the [Gist](https://medium.com/@2bhere4u/angular-5-material-design-checkbox-array-reactive-forms-handle-3885dde366ca)